# Show different count of different remarks for distinct users

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

Please I need solution for a project I am currently working on

Users are assigned a task every week and they submit an answer. They are scored either Won or Lost for that week on the Rating Table.

I need a way to view all Users from the Rating Tables to see the number of tasks they have Won and Lost side by side

Below is the RATINGS Table of 10 Entries for 5 Users

```
**id**             **username**          **date**                    **remarks**

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  1                    John              2017-09-02                      Won    
  2                    Kyle              2017-09-02                      Lost    
  3                    Danny             2017-09-02                      Won    
  4                    Mike              2017-09-02                      Won    
  5                    Alli              2017-09-02                      Won    
  6                    Kyle              2017-09-09                      Lost    
  7                    John              2017-09-09                      Won    
  8                    Danny             2017-09-09                      Lost    
  9                    Mike              2017-09-09                      Lost    
  10                   Alli              2017-09-09                      Won
```

I need to pull out the Result to look this way:

```
Username   Total_tasks    Won      Lost 

 john          2           2         0    
 kyle          2           0         2   
 danny         2           1         1
 mike          2           1         1
 alli          2           2         0
```

Comment: what you want is a simple `group by` query. you should have a look at MySQL functions at first. also, what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since aggregate functions, including `count` ignore nulls, a simple trick you can use to to count a bunch of case expressions:

```
SELECT   username,
         COUNT(*) AS total_tasks
         COUNT(CASE remarks WHEN 'Won' THEN 1 END) AS won,
         COUNT(CASE remarks WHEN 'Lost' THEN 1 END) AS lost
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: We usually use SUM for this - otherwise (warnings permitted) you could just as well use 'foo' as 1

Comment: please your mysql query looks okay, the total tasks are working. But i am getting an error for the Won and Lost saying an Alias was expedted before won